# when back button is pressed, cursor loader should restart

Tags: android, android-cursorloader

I have a listFragment and when an item of the list is clicked it starts a new activity. When back button is pressed, the list is shown again. Im using cursor Loaders so, I want to know if is there an easy way to refresh the cursor loader when back button is pressed. This is because the new activity changes the contents of the list.

**Edit:**

```
public class ListWordFragment extends SherlockListFragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    private static String TAG = ListWordFragment.class.getSimpleName();
    private CursorLoader cursorLoader;

    // Loader
    private static final int URL_LOADER = 0;
    private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
    public static LoaderManager mLoaderManager;

    // ActionBar
    private AutoCompleteTextView autoCompView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_words, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        ListView list = getListView();


        String[] from = new String[] { Word.NAME, Word.TYPE, Word.TRANSLATE };
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.textView_word, R.id.textView_type,
                R.id.textView_translate };

        adapter = new ListWordAdapter(getSherlockActivity(),
                R.layout.row_list_words, null, from, to, 0);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        mLoaderManager = getLoaderManager();
        mLoaderManager.initLoader(URL_LOADER, null, this);

    }



    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        fillRow(l, id, position, false);

    }

    private void fillRow(ListView l, long ide, int position, boolean firstCall) {

        Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
                Uri.withAppendedPath(WordListProvider.WORDS_CONTENT_URI,
                        String.valueOf(ide)), null, null, null, null);

        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){

        String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Word.ID));
        String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Word.NAME));
        String type = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Word.TYPE));
        String translate = cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(Word.TRANSLATE));
        String example = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Word.EXAMPLE));
        String note = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Word.NOTE));

        // Master/Detail
        if ((getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
                && (getResources().getString(R.string.selected_configuration)
                        .equals(Constants.CONFIGURATION_LARGE))) {

            WordDetailFragment frag = (WordDetailFragment) getFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.word_detail_fragment);

            if (frag != null) {
                frag.setId(id);
                frag.setName(name);
                frag.setType(type);
                frag.setTranslate(translate);
                frag.setExample(example);
                frag.setNote(note);
            }

        } else if (firstCall) {
            // Do nothing

        } else {

            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                    WordDetailActivity.class);

            i.putExtra(Word.ID, id);
            i.putExtra(Word.NAME, name);
            i.putExtra(Word.TYPE, type);
            i.putExtra(Word.TRANSLATE, translate);
            i.putExtra(Word.EXAMPLE, example);
            i.putExtra(Word.NOTE, note);

            startActivity(i);
        }
        cursor.close();
        }

    }

    public void onWordSaved() {
        getLoaderManager().restartLoader(URL_LOADER, null, this);    
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int loaderID, Bundle bundle) {
        String[] projection = { Word.ID, Word.NAME, Word.TYPE, Word.TRANSLATE,
                Word.EXAMPLE, Word.NOTE };

        /* Takes action based on the ID of the Loader that's being created */

        switch (loaderID) {
        case URL_LOADER:

            // Returns a new CursorLoader
            cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(getSherlockActivity(), // Parent
                                                                    // activity
                    // context
                    WordListProvider.WORDS_CONTENT_URI, // Table to query
                    projection, // Projection to return
                    null, // No selection clause
                    null, // No selection arguments
                    null // Default sort order
            );
            return cursorLoader;
        default:
            // An invalid id was passed in
            return null;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
        adapter.swapCursor(cursor);
    }


    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {   
        adapter.swapCursor(null);
    }


}
```

Comment: Did you try overriding onResume() and refresh from there?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding to your Fragment class:

```
@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    getLoaderManager().restartLoader(URL_LOADER, null, this); 
}


public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    adapter.swapCursor(null);
}
```

To clear up your efficiency concern: When you call the initial init, it will start, but restartLoader on the same ID will automatically cancel that previous request and start a new one. So it won't get executed fully twice on activity start up.

More info in [Google Loader Dev Doco](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html#restarting).

Comment: Yes, this does the trick. But I want this to get called only if back button is presed.

Comment: Let me explain better. Your solution works but when my list is shown the first time the onActivityCreated method does the query. If I try to requery on the resume method, it will do the query twice and thats not efficient.

Comment: Remove it from onActivityCreated and just put the query in the onResume, it will get called only once (including when the activity it first created)

Comment: I cant do that because all the purpose of the cursor loader will be lost.

Comment: Ok, maybe try this one. I'm not sure how you're implementing your CursorLoader, so maybe paste some code so we can get a better picture?

Comment: Done. Its pretty much like the ones we can find in tutorials.

Comment: I made it work!!. Turns out that I was implemented something useless that was avoiding the cursor loader to work properly. Now, pressing the back button the cursor loaders magically updates the cursor. I dont have to do anything. :). Thanks anyway for your time!!

Comment: @kiduxa do you remember what you were doing, because I'm having the same problem.